# Why are sinks always rounded?

Tags: usability, user-behavior, physical, industrial-design, product-design

I've noticed a trend recently that some sinks have a flat base, but they seem to be few and far between. Are there any reasons related to UX for why sinks have traditionally always been round?

Comment: A rounded sink is easier to clean.

Comment: Sacha Greif on [the flat sink](http://sachagreif.com/the-flat-sink/)

Comment: Interesting point: laundry sinks (at least here in Australia) are generally square with flat sides and bottoms. It seems indeed to be a function of depth and volume.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Commercial sinks are "flat" by industrial design. There is a specific sequence for hand cleaning dishes that specifies three compartments for washing, rinsing and sanitizing.

http://www.healthdepartment.org/Environmental/Food%20Scores/3%20compartment%20sink.pdf

They are designed to be filled with water. They are flat to hold the maximum volume of water and items to be washed. It's all based on a tried and true design tested in countless restaurant kitchens.

Residential use sink design is driven by style but favors roundness for a few reasons that I can merely speculate on.

1. They originate from washing bowls and they likely continue the legacy of that design.
2. The utility of a rounded design is favorable in residential use because it's easier to clean and it splashes much less when water is running in an empty sink. A flat is better if the sink is deep and I notice that the deepr a sink design, the flatter it is.

At my (tech not food service) job, the kitchen sink is a shallow flat design and it sprays everywhere when the water is turned on. Everybody avoids it.

Answer (score 8):

Most domestic sinks (but not all) are rounded because:

1. They are **cheaper to make**, as you can simply press them out of a flat piece of steel.  You can't press out corners easily like this as they will tear in the pressing process.
2. They are **easier to clean** with a sponge or cloth.  The same applies to dog bowls by the way, which is why squared dog bowls are very rare.
3. They are **stronger** due to their geometry.
4. People are **used to them**.

[image]

**Comercial sinks are often squared**, as well as domestic sinks that have special purposes.  My home sink is squared for example, so that it fits my oven trays perfectly.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Flat sinks are common in industrial settings. They're usually filled completely and so having something that holds the largest volume and where things stack easily and you have a stable surface.

For the home you tend to get rounded sinks. As @Itumac mentioned it's at least partially from historical reasons. But there are utilitarian ones too.

- Flat sinks tend to splash when filled - rounded do not
- Flat sinks take more effort to clean and maintain since they drain less effectively and have "corners".
- Flat sinks take much more water to be useful. With a rounded sink you can fill the bottom of the bowl rapidly to a useful depth for handwashing or cleaning.
- Rounded sinks hold less water - which is useful in residential settings when less water is normally needed.

I'd say the rise of flat sinks in the home is more a fashion issue of people liking a more industrial look to their kitchens and bathrooms.

Answer (score 0):

The trend must be based on style rather than function. Here is a [commentary on flat sinks in the home.](http://sachagreif.com/the-flat-sink/)

In kitchens, flat sinks have always been around.

A flat sink provides a better work surface for washing dishes, food, utensils.

Stainless steel sinks are also more popular in kitchens because the material is more resilient than other comparably priced materials. Also, making a flat bottom steel sink is easier than a rounded steel sink.

Answer (score 0):

If the bottom is flat you have to mount it perfectly horizontal or the high  end won't drain properly.  With a rounded profile there's more margin for error.